# How does function template ordering de-prioritize empty function parameter packs in C++?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, variadic-templates, overload-resolution

In the C++20 standard, [[temp.func.order]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.func.order#example-5) contains the following non-normative example:

```
template<class T, class... U> void f(T, U...);          // #1
template<class T            > void f(T);                // #2
template<class T, class... U> void g(T*, U...);         // #3
template<class T            > void g(T);                // #4

void h(int i) {
  f(&i);                                                // OK: calls #2
  g(&i);                                                // OK: calls #3
}
```

My question: What normative language and reasoning leads to `f(&i)` calling `#2`, as opposed to neither definition of `f` being more specialized than the other and the program being ill-formed on account of an ambiguous call?

My obviously incorrect reading of that section goes as follows:

- Calculate "transformed" versions of #1 and #2, which in both cases will be `void f(int *)`.
- Perform type deduction of each transformed function against the other template, which in both cases will succeed and result in `f<int*>`.
- Check a bunch of conditions that don't hold, and end up at [13.7.7.3 (6.5)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.func.order#6.5): "neither template is more specialized than the other"

So something is not clear to me about the partial ordering of function templates.

The answer seems to be in [[temp.deduct.partial]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.deduct.partial#11)

Comment: I believe the presence of a parameter pack counts as "one template is more constrained than the other" and is subject [temp.constr.order](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.constr.order) but I'm not sure exactly how that's spelled out

Answer (score 2):

> What normative language and reasoning leads to `f(&i)` calling #2

This can be explained using [temp.deduct.partial#11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.deduct.partial#11) which states:

> If, after considering the above, function template F is at least as specialized as function template G and vice-versa, and **if G has a trailing function parameter pack for which F does not have a corresponding parameter, and if F does not have a trailing function parameter pack, then F is more specialized than G.**

(emphasis mine)

Basically the above tie breaker is applied and so the `#2` version is choosen over `#1`.

Comment: A question with the language-lawyer tag asking for normative language should be answered with a citation to the standard, not cppreference.

Comment: @NathanPierson I've added the citation from the standard also.